# Angular.json - How do I enforce CLI to inject script tags to head instead of body?.

Tags: angular-cli-v6, angular-cli-v7

How do I enforce CLI to inject script tags to head instead of body?.

AngularCLI 6 onwards does not eject webpack anymore. so I started exploring angular.json which basically is the replacement of angular-cli.json.

In previous version( 1.6.0 ) the way I approached this was I ejected to webpack and in webpack I used HTMLWebpackPlugin to enforce the scripts tobe injected to head. This worked great.

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
"template": "./src/index.html",
"filename": "./index.html",
"hash": false,
<i>"inject": "head",</i>
"compile": true,
...
```

Now with angular cli 6.0 or 7.0 since we cant eject webpack anymore how do I achieve the same. I dont see any inject option in angular.json file.

please help.

Comment: Why not just add them directly to the head in the actual index.html